# Detatch subdirectory into separate git repository - On github

Tags: git, github

Ive got a project on github which has ended up with a project "inside" and I would like to do a move like described in [detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository).

My added question is, how do i effectuate this on github as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it will rewrite all SHA1 for the current project and the new one, the safest course of action would be:

- create 2 new projects
- push 2 local projects to the new GitHub projects
- alert everyone who has already forked your current GitHub project
- **[delete](http://help.github.com/deleting-a-repo/)** the current GitHub project.
  Go to the repository homepage → Admin → Delete this repository
  (note: Deleting a private repo will delete all forks of the repo. Deleting a public repo will not.)